# python/django request.POST not working

Tags: django, post, request

i am trying to read the value from the radio.input in the form below using

```
p = get_object_or_404(Plan,pk=plan_id)
selected_event = p.event_set.get(pk=request.POST['event'])
```

but when i try to access the webpage,it throws an error: "Key 'event' not found in `<QueryDict: {}>"`
Please help. thanks in advance!

```
<form action="/orchidpoll/{{plan.id}}/vote" type="get">
{% for event in plan.event_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="event" id="event{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ event.id }}" />
    <label><a href="/orchidpoll/{{ plan.id }}/{{event.id}}">{{ event.name }}</a></label><br />
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Vote"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your form tag is correct. It shouldn't have a `type` attribute. It should be:

```
<form action="/orchidpoll/{{plan.id}}/vote" method="post">
```